# Can you say "focus at"?

Tags: word-usage

I understand that the intransitive use of the verb "focus " is often followed by the preposition "on," but is it OK to say "focus at" instead of "focus on?"  If not, why?
 Below is one of the definitions of the verb I found in my dictionary.

to direct your attention or effort at something specific.

Comment: It is possible. But I have seen it mainly with "on" as a verb. As for using "at" I have seen it more with the noun form. Prepositions usage usually doesn't  have any special reason. So answering your "why" question is difficult.

Comment: In general, [people just don't say "focus at".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=focus+at%2Cfocus+on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfocus%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfocus%20on%3B%2Cc0)  So I would say "Don't say *focus at*, because you'll sound weird."

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without some examples.

Answer (score 1):

*To focus on something* is a collocation, like *to direct at something*; although the former is the only one possible (according to the Oxford Collocation dictionary, at least), whereas the verb *to direct* may collocate with different prepositions (at, into, to, toward(s), and a few others).

Why? Because it's a set phrase, like *to look forward to*, *to be afraid of*, *to be angry with* and so on.

To deside whether *to focus* may be used with "at" is impossible without a context